# how to set date day name from datepicker as column name in mysql database..?

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

for e.g. if i pick date from datepicker and if that day is wednesday i want to get all data from "wed" column having particualr value only.....

i need php code and mysql qyery for this??

```
-- Table structure for table `list`
--

CREATE TABLE `list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Mon` char(1) default NULL,
  `Tue` char(1) default NULL,
  `Wed` char(1) default NULL,
  `Thur` char(1) default NULL,
  `Fri` char(1) default NULL,
  `Sat` char(1) default NULL,
  `Sun` char(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: *"i need php mysql code for this"* - Just click on the "Create PHP code" in phpmyadmin in a SELECT query with a WHERE clause, *"done like dinner"*.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - As you can see, we're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to give you code. Show us what you've tried so far and we'll help you find your errors. Show us your thoughts. Nobody on stackoverflow will write code for you. You should edit your question and show us what you've tried, otherwise it will get downvoted quite fast.

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- .... but i want filter data according to date selected from datepicker....how to do that

Comment: you're going to have to post all relevant code for this; it's anybody's ballgame really. This including php/html/js/datepicker codes etc. But the general comment I left to do this in phpmyadmin is the same logic.

Comment: $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', '201308131830');

echo $datetime->format('D');//you can get your day name here

Comment: @Fred-ii-  how date identify perticular column name??? plz give me code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For php code

```
$weekday[0]="Sun";
$weekday[1]="Mon";
$weekday[2]="Tues";
$weekday[3]="Wed";
$weekday[4]="Thur";
$weekday[5]="Fri";
$weekday[6]="Sat";


$date = '2011/10/14'; 
$dayName = date('D', strtotime($date));
$dayNumber = date('N', strtotime($date));
echo $dayName; //date name 
$prefix = $weekday[$dayNumber]; //custom date name
$query = "select * from table_name where $prefix = 'Y'";
```

Comment: I have change my answer please let me know it's working or not

Comment: You can use daterangepicker from here http://www.daterangepicker.com/ or https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: .. Please tell me if it is right way .. For query.    SELECT ..FROM... WHERE $weekday[$date]='Y'.     ,. How do you assign weekday name ?  According to column name or its predefined..?  Yes.,Your code is working..

Comment: i have added query in my answer